# What changes to Oracle installation are needed to work with Microsoft MSDTC

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, msdtc, distributed-transactions

We have windows 2008 and 2003 servers that use COM PLUS-MSDTC and distributed transactions with 11g(11.2.0.3) running on SunOS and SPARC hardware.  The oracle server was installed years ago by a DBA that is long gone.

We have built a new oracle server same version.  Problem is that COM PLUS-MSDTC and distributed transactions do not work with the new server and our current DBA has never installed a server that is supposed to work with COM PLUS-MSDTC and distributed transactions.

If we point our windows server to the existing oracle server no problem, we point it to new one and our COM PLUS apps just hang.

Is there something that needs to be done to the Oracle installation to allow it to work with COM PLUS-MSDTC and distributed transactions?  Some script or setting?